# compement set of $A=${$1,{1\over 2},{1\over 3},{1\over 4},...$}

Tags: general-topology

If

$A=${$1,{1\over 2},{1\over 3},{1\over 4},{1\over 5}, ...$}

That's mean:

${A={1\over n}} , n\in\mathbb{N}$

1- Find the compement set $A^c$

2- Then explain $A^c$ not open.

1- I think

$A^c=(-\infty,0] \cup ({1\over k+1},{1\over k}) \cup (1, \infty)$

True ?

I think $({1\over k+1},{1\over k})$ false but i don't know what the correct interval.

2-  I know 0 element in $A^c$, but 0 not element in $int(A)$

So $A^c$ not open.

True ?

Comment: You have correctly answered the question, however, in 2) i change the argument saying that 0 is not a interior point of  $A^c$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complement depends on the ambient: if it's $\mathbb R$ your answer is correct, and so the second. You can also prove it by showing that $\overline {A}$ is different from $A$, so $A$ is not closed and $A^C$ not open.

Comment: Sorry i was edit the question, i want $A^c$

Comment: Yes, sorry I showed that $A^C$ is not closed! Just edited

Comment: Thank you so much, is the complement set $A^c$ true ? And the number $k$ in $\mathbb{N}$ or $\mathbb{R}$ or what ?

Comment: The complement set is true and $k \in \mathbb N$.

Comment: Sure, Sorry I forgot.